# Null exception при сохранении в БД записи, которая имеет внешний ключ на другую таблицу

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Есть две сущности: спортсмены и соревнование, которые находятся в связи ManyToOne. Т.е. несколько спортсменов участвуют в одном соревновании. В сущности спортсмен указана данная связь как ManyToOne и проблема в том, что я хочу вначале ввести несколько спортсменов, а потом распределить их по соревнованиям и когда я создаю запись спортсмен, то автоматически генерируется внешний ключ на таблицу "соревнования", но т.к. запись в таблице "соревнования" отсутствует(т.е. внешний ключ ссыылается на null), то я получаю эксепцию, как это пофиксить?
Вот сущности:
Спортсмены

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sportsmans")
public class Sportsman {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String alias;

private int growth;

private int weight;

private int lengthOfHands;

private int countOfLose;

private int countOfWin;

private int countOfDraw;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="fights_id")
private Fight fight;
/* getters and setters */
}
```

Соревнование

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fights")
public class Fight {

@Id
@Column(name = "fight_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long fightId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fight", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Sportsman> sportsmans = new HashSet<>();

private Long identifWin;

private Long identifEvent;

public Long getId() {
    return fightId;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.fightId = id;
}
}
```

Метод в сервисе, который отвечает за добавление записи в таблицу "Спорсмены" реализован следующим образом:

```
public void addSportsman(String firstName, String lastName, String alias) {
    Sportsman sportsman = new Sportsman();
    sportsman.setFirstName(firstName);
    sportsman.setLastName(lastName);
    sportsman.setAlias(alias);

    sportsmanRepo.save(sportsman);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще, я допустил ошибку когда маппил две таблицы- неправильно указал название foreign key:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="fights_id")
private Fight fight;
/* getters and setters */
}
```

Не fight**s**_id, а fight_id